# How to get bounds of bitmap inside ImageView

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I use ImageView to proceed bitmap. Sample code below:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

ImageView has "match_parent" params and takes all screen's area till buttons in bottom and scaleType=fitCenter, so a bitmap is shown proportional(what i want), but with visible bounds. Further, i need to draw rectangle area inside bitmap to select portion of bitmap to crop. But i need to get bound coordы of this bitmap inside ImageView that rectangle i draw not to move out of bitmap. See picture with problem. For pictures with height more than width it needs to get Xleft(X1) and Xright(X2) coords, and for pictures with height less than width it needs to get Ytop and Ybottom coord.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybRYL.jpg)